# C# and links to JS functions

Tags: c#, javascript, html, xpath, windows-phone-8

I want to create an application for WP8 that shows the content of a web page. I'm not writing the code yet, but but i know that i can take the page content using xpath. My problem is that the content i want to take is not in a single page. I have to press the "Next" button to go to the next page. The code for the button is this.

```
<td class="pager-next" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
       <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton2" class="buttondiego buttondiego_small buttondiego_arrow" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton2','')"></a>
</td>
```

And this is the JS function in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Is it possible to go to the next page with my code? How should i do?

Comment: You should at least post the code of the form, and a link to that page wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This for example.
http://www.starcomics.com/UsciteMensili.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to:

- Deeply **analyze their JavaScript**, and do some reverse engineering on the required POST values to fetch a specific page. You can see what requests are sent using Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools network view. The URL definitely is

  ```
  <http://www.starcomics.com/UsciteMensili.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
  ```

  but simply POSTing the monitored "interesting looking" fields

  ```
  __ASYNCPOST:true
  __EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataPager2$ctl00$lnkNextPage
  ```

  was not sufficient.
- Alternatively, you could use some **headless browser** implementation which actually executes the JavaScript. They will be more complicated to setup and be less performant, but you won't have to care about the logic behind loading the pages any more. I think the most common used headless browser is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), but I don't know whether and how to employ it with Windows Phone and C#, you might want to set it up on your own server and proxy the data.

Comment: Every time i put something in the query string i get the error message  
> Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.